# htaccess redirect looping issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a htaccess modrewrite rule to redirect, i have made my own but it redirects again and again and from a loop so it is not working from my side.

http://freemp3tx.com/anything to http://freemp3tx.com/anything-mp3-download.html

htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-mp3-download.html$ index.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The rule you have posted above already works to load `anything-mp3-download.html` into `index.php?search=`?  Do you need assistance with the redirection from `/anything` to `/anything-mp3-download.html`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from `anything` to `anything-mp3-download.html`, you must prevent an endless loop with a `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-mp3-download.html$
RewriteRule .* $0-mp3-download.html [L]
```